# Display a single row from a database in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

I want to display only the first names in a `datagridview`. This is my query, but it isn't returning anything:

```
sc.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from myEmployees where JobRole ='Waiter'";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {                            
        dgNames.DataSource = dr["firstName"];
        count++                      
   }         
}            
sc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the Datasource to be just one property. What you can do instead is define a column in your gridview that's bound to the first name column and then you set te Grid's Datasource to be the whole collection of objects returned.

Secondly, you can simply bind the Datareader to the grid, no need to do the while loop at all.

## Update

```
dgNames.AutogenerateColumns=false;
dgNames.Columns.Add("firstName","firstName");
dgNames.DataSource=dr;
```

If you want to know how many records were returned, simply count the number of rows in the grid after is bound... Or load a datatable with the Datareader, and bind the Dataable to the grid instead of binding the Datareader. The DataTables.Rows.Count will tell you how many records were returned.

Comment: Could you give me a snippet please

Comment: @tacit are you using Winforms or asp.net?

Comment: Hmm what AutogenerateColumns doesn't really recognize it and could you edit this using my code so i can understand which parts i need and dont need

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from MSDN (google 'datagridview' and it's right at the top).  Sroll to the bottom, and there is sample code that demonstrates what how to do what you're asking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

As Icarus says -- you can just bind the data without examining it row-by-row like you're trying to do.  But if you do want to go row-by-row, you can

```
...
dgNames.Rows.Add(dr["firstName"]);
...
```

Also -- you don't need to increment a datareader that's in a while loop like you're using.

Comment: Im not incrementing the datareader im just counting how many records are returned plus the line above throws an exception

Comment: the argument might need to be a string array -- look up the `rows` property at the link above and it talks specifically about it -- in any case, I can't actually do your code for you (without a lot more information from you), so best I can do is give you the link to the answer.  Check out the MSDN article -- it is "the manual", as it were, and has a working example.  Also -- you can call rowcount on your datagridveiw after it is bound if you want a rowcount -- up to you, but anyway, fwiw.

Comment: Thanks mate I am looking at the link see if I can understand it thanks a lot I appreciate your help